# Is it possible to use train_test_split and KFold

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a simple dataset. First I tried to split the dataset using `train_test_split()`. Then I tried to use `KFold()`. The code is given below

```
def call(X_train: ndarray,X_test: ndarray,y_train: ndarray,y_test: ndarray,k: int,repetitions: int,
) -> Dict:
        rep_sub = []
        for reps in range(repetitions):
            fold_sub = []
            kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True)
            for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train):
                preds = LinearRegression().fit(X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index]).predict(X_test[test_index])
                sub = preds - y_test[test_index]
                fold_sub.extend(sub)
            rep_sub.extend(fold_sub)
        return rep_sub

if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
    y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    all_preds = call(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, k=2, repetitions=2)
```

I am getting the error `IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3`

Would you mind explaining what I am doing wrong here? I need to use `5 fold holdout external validation`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KFold(X)` will create `k` - `(train, test)` subset of indices out of supplied `X`. So you can only index into the `X`. What you are trying to do is index `test` indices into something which is not `X`. Without commenting on why are using this strange combination of `train_test_split` and `KFold`, you should be using `test_index` to index into supplied `X_train` or just ignore it. Below are two ways you can use it (again not commenting on why you want to use it this way):

#### Case 1

```
preds = LinearRegression().fit(
    X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index]).predict(X_train[test_index])
sub = preds - y_train[test_index]
```

#### Case 2

```
preds = LinearRegression().fit(
    X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index]).predict(X_test)
sub = preds - y_test
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I am trying to create all `sub` as the same dimension. If I use `k=2` then I am getting the same dimension `sub` but if I use `k=3` I am getting different dimensions for `sub`. Could you give me any idea (or any way) to get the same dimensions of `sub` for all `k`. Say, for example, if I use `k=3`, I will get ` 3 sub` and all of them has the same dimension. Again, if I use `k=2`, I will get `4 sub` and all of them has the same dimension. It does not mean that, the dimensions of `sub` will be the same for  `k=3` and `k=2` (they could different).